# sql query to csv file in cron job

Tags: php, sql, csv, cron

Is it possible to have a sql query in a cron job? 
I use the code under to add the query in a csv file. But want to put it in a cron job in a php file. I know how to add cron jobs, but not sure how the correct way to call the database and the query in a php script.

i use this to access the  database:

```
 psql -U www -d databasename
```

And this syntax to write to csv file:

```
\f ';'
    \a
    \t
    \o /tmp/moocow.csv
    SELECT foo,bar FROM whatever;
    \o
    \q
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You don't know how to access the database from PHP? Or you don't know how to run a PHP script from `cron`?

Comment: For the first, see the `pg_XXX` functions in PHP.

Comment: I think it would be better to create a .php file that returns an excel with the data you want. Then assign a cron job to hit that end point / file.

Comment: are you using linux cron job ?

Comment: if yes it is quite possible just make sql connection just like u connect database from CLI

Comment: Im using linux cron job

Comment: $connection = ssh2_connect('SERVER IP', 22); 

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, 'DESTINATION IP', 3307);

trying to use this syntax: $db = new mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD', 
                         'dbname', 3307, $tunnel)
    or die ('Fail: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: but how to add the  : \f ';'
    \a
    \t
    \o /tmp/moocow.csv
    SELECT foo,bar FROM whatever;
    \o
    \q

Comment: ws trying to echo it, but it dident like it

Comment: write a PHP script that works from the command line, using normal PHP/mysqli syntax, including your SQL. Then tell cron simply to execute the script. If you don't know how to run a SQL query in PHP then you can find literally hundreds of examples online for the mysqli library, including on this site. And the same for examples of how to get PHP to output to a CSV file (hint, not the way you appear to be doing it).